# how to train a neural network with array as an label i.e [1,0] in tensorflow 2.0

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am training an image classifier model in which I have taken the image and converted it into an array of shape 50*50*1 and the label of that image is `[0,1]`. It is a horse or a human classifier i.e for horses it's `[0,1]`  for humans it's `[1,0]`. I tried using this CNN network but failed.

```
model_new = Sequential([Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu',input_shape=(50, 50,1)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Dropout(0.2),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1)
])
model_new.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),metrics=['accuracy'])

model_new.fit(X, Y, epochs=10,validation_data=(test_x, test_y))
```

`X` is an image array of size `50,50,1` and `Y` is array `[1,0]`. Is there anything wrong with the code? If so, how should I change it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Dense(1)` to `Dense(2)` and use `tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy`